# How can I output the result of find and grep as filename => found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

How can I combine the result of commands `find` and `grep` in the format: `filename: => string`?

For example, `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name .env -exec grep 'CURRENT_ENV' {} \;` The command will display me the line when `CURRENT_ENV`string found, e.g. `CURRENT_ENV=staging`. I want to modify the output in the follow way: `./site1.com: CURRENT_ENV=staging`.

I can't understand How can I reach that. Is it possible?

Comment: it's software so **anything** is possible, you never need to ask "Is it possible?".

Comment: @EdMorton "Is it possible to ... without changing the source code of common utilities?" :)

Comment: @Arkadiy The answer is always "yes".

Comment: Is it possible to write a program that tells you whether or not an algorithm will eventually terminate?

Comment: I know what you're getting at but practically - yes. The global state space of a system is the combination of the values of all variables in that system. So if you can reach all of those without discovering livelock then the PUT will terminate. Google Promela, Spin, VFSM, Verisoft for examples of programs that traverse the global state space of a given program testing for deadlock, livelock, LTL specs, etc. IIRC there's a good discussion of it in the BLTJ article written by Holzmann around 2002 if you can find it online (I can't). And no, I won't be continuing a discussion of computing theory,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>   -H, --with-filename
>           Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when
>           there is more than one file to search.
> ```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html